# Get filename and extension where path contains multiple period characters '.'

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove just the file extension with a file path that contains multiple period characters. Other questions have suggested using `tools::file_path_sans_ext` but it doesn't seem to work for paths with more than one period. Is there another method or workaround I can use.

```
path <- "BONCAT_CE_7142-Q-ConsG09/IMG_Data/87243.assembled.bin_assignment"
tools::file_path_sans_ext(path)
#> "BONCAT_CE_7142-Q-ConsG09/IMG_Data/87243.assembled.bin_assignment"
```

WRONG! should be `BONCAT_CE_7142-Q-ConsG09/IMG_Data/87243.assembled`

Comment: If you look at the code for the function in the console, you can see it uses `sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", x)` which assumes that a file extension is just alphanumeric, a-zA-z0-9 only - which is also in the help file at `?tools::file_path_sans_ext` - "*(Only purely alphanumeric extensions are recognized.)*"

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use a little bit regular expression:

```
sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", path)
# [1] "BONCAT_CE_7142-Q-ConsG09/IMG_Data/87243.assembled"
```

This removes everything after the last period(inclusive) of the string, with `$` matches the end of String; `[^.]*` match a non-period sequence and a period `\\.`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to port as best I could the python `splitext` function. It handles some corner cases that I was seeing as well.

```
splitext <- function(x) {
    periods <- gregexpr("\\.", x)[[1]]
    if ( periods[1] == -1) {
        result <- c(x, "") 
    }
    else if (length(periods) == 1 ) {
        result <- c( substr(x, 1, periods[1] - 1), substring(x, periods[1] + 1))
    } 
    else {
        result <- c( substr(x, 1, periods[-1] - 1), substring(x, periods[-1] + 1))
    }
    result
}
```