# How to strip off a file ending but only when it starts with a non-digit? (a regex problem related to file_path_sans_ext)

Tags: r, regex

I would like to write a function `rm_ext` similar to `tools::file_path_sans_ext` but does not strip off file endings if they start with a digit. By replacing `[:alnum:]` by `[:alpha:]` in `tools::file_path_sans_ext` I almost got there, but if the base name of the file ends in a dot itself, it fails:

```
rm_ext <- function(x) sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alpha:]]+$", "\\1", x) # adapted from tools::file_path_sans_ext()
rm_ext("test.string.with.dots.but.ending.alpha=0.25.rda") # works
rm_ext("test.string.with.dots.but.without.ending.alpha=0.25") # works
rm_ext("test.string.with.dots.but.ending.alpha=0.25.") # fails (should remove the final . too)
```

I tried to match `[:alpha:]` or EOL, but that didn't make the last case work.

Note: As a comparison, `tools::file_path_sans_ext` (of course) fails, see `tools::file_path_sans_ext("test.string.with.dots.but.without.ending=0.25")`. Also note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380470/get-filename-and-extension-where-path-contains-multiple-period-characters) is somewhat related but different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\.(?:[^0-9.][^.]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PzCbSC/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C.(%3F%3A%5B%5E0-9.%5D%5B%5E.%5D*)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:[^0-9.][^.]*)?` - an optional sequence of a char other than a dot and a digit and then any 0+ chars other than a dot
- `$` - end of string.

In the code:

```
sub("\\.(?:[^0-9.][^.]*)?$", "", x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, these two links are great.